# Should I upload perl 'xt' tests to CPAN?

Tags: perl

Some time ago the new thing appeared in the Perl world. The thing is to create
`xt` directory in the module source code and to place there tests that should
be run only by author. The idea of `xt` tests is that they are not run when
the module is installed from CPAN.

I was thinking that if the tests are not needed for the installation process
there is no need to upload that tests to CPAN. My idea was to have these tests
in my VSC, but not to put them in the tar.gz file this is uploaded to CPAN.

But now there are a lot of CPAN modules that have `xt` directory in it. I have
a local CPAN copy and I searched for such modules:

```
$ find -iname "*.tar*" -exec tar tf {} \; | grep "/xt/" &> modules_with_xt_dir
$ cat modules_with_xt_dir |sort --random-sort|uniq|head
CatalystX-Dispatcher-AsGraph-0.01/xt/03_pod.t
Religion-Bible-Reference-0.014/xt/release/perl-critic.t
DBIx-Custom-0.1674/xt/dbix-connector.t
Geo-Distance-XS-0.09/xt/
FBP-Perl-0.21/xt/pod.t
Getopt-Compact-WithCmd-0.14/xt/01_podspell.t
Dist-Zilla-Plugin-CheckExtraTests-0.004/xt/release/pod-coverage.t
MooseX-GlobRef-0.07/xt/pod_spellrc
Web-Request-0.09/xt/release/pod-syntax.t
Amon2-2.52/eg/Hello/xt/perlcriticrc
```

My question is about best pactices. What is best? To upload `xt` tests to
CPAN, or not to upload? What are the advantages of the decision?

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that the best practice is to upload.

The benefit is that it lets people hack and patch your code and still be able to run the full test suite. Helps with people writing patches - and hurts nobody.

Comment: I'm not sure that hacking the code that you get from tar.gz file is the best thing. I think that the better solution is to checkout the source code from some version control system. Then you will get the exact code the author is working on and you will get history of commits that gives you additional information that can help you improve to software.

Comment: If someone's using your CPAN module, they will almost certainly fetch the tarball from CPAN if they find something they need to change. There's no downside to putting the author tests into the CPAN release, and if they help a single user to fix an issue they experienced, they've served their purpose.

Comment: Tests also are a kind of documentation because they show how things should (or should not) be called, used or handled. It always makes sense to distribute these to users, unless you want to hide something from them. But that would be weird indeed, wouldn't it?

Comment: +1 to uploading xt/ to CPAN. For precisely the reasons stated.